# What is the appropriate number format for accounting?

Tags: excel, number-formatting

I tried everywhere and got few formats like this:

```
 "_(\"$\"* #,##0.00_);_(\"$\"* \\(#,##0.00\\);_(\"$\"* \"-\"??_);_(@_)"
```

But on applying this I couldn't get the result as in Excel. I mean the currency symbol should appear on the left side of a cell, while the numbers should get displayed on the right side of the cell.

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what results you should get with different inputs? Otherwise it looks like you want accounting help, which would be off-topic.

Comment: Is there a problem with the built in formats that Excel offers?

Comment: if you give input as 15000 in excel and set the number format to Currency,it gives a result as "    $15,000.00".              When you give the same number in excel and set the number format to Accounting, it gives a result as "$   15,000.00".i need to know,how to apply this accounting number format.Please refer the below link for reference http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/currency-vs-accounting.html

Comment: use of this number format "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)" also,gives a wrong result like this "_($*15,000.00_)"   . Am i missing anything else? All the accounting number formats i used gives the same result.Please help me out....

Comment: You wrote "But on applying this I couldn't get the result as in Excel." So where are you applying the format and expecting this result? Somewhere outside Excel? If so where?

Answer (score 0):

Excel has the format you describe built in (using Excel 2010).

Example of un-formatted cells:

[image: Unformatted Cells]

1. Highlight the cells (or entire column) you want to format
2. Select the "Format" button from the Ribbon
3. Click "Format Cells"

[image: Steps to take]

1. Select "Accounting"
2. Select "Ok"

[image: Format Cells]

Your cells will now be formatted with the dollar sign on the left and the values on the right. Negative values will be surrounded in parenthesis

[image: Formatted cells]

Comment: Thank You @Andy.I need to know what number format is used for Accounting.If it is number,the number format will be like this "##,#00.00".Like wise what number format is used for Accounting?